# Word describing combination of disgust and pride

Tags: single-word-requests

As a software engineer, I need a word for this. I find myself writing code which is at once fugly (not to be shown to anyone) but also somewhat clever and surprising (at least I think so).

Sample sentence: Damn, this code makes me feel _____!

Comment: *unmaintainable,*  *write-only*

Comment: Disgust and pride are feelings one has.  Your sample sentence does not ask for that.

Comment: To @Jim's comment: You couldn't plug in "Damn, this code is disgust and pride", so the example sentence doesn't work. Do you mean something like "code that may make one feel a combination of disgust and pride" or "Damn, this code fills me with feelings of ____." Edit accordingly and the close votes will likely to lifted.

Comment: I've occasionally used "bad magic" for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Jim updated sample sentence :)

Comment: ...similar to the ["pride and revulsion"](https://bit.ly/3vqKXG8) feeling as expressed by Tom Duff on his own discovery of the [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device#Original_version).

Comment: If you'll spring for two words, I like **guilty pleasure**.

Comment: @TimonvanderBerg Please accept my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Damn, this **hack** makes me feel **ambivalent**!

What is a single word to describe the "feeling" of conflicting emotions of disgust (self-loathing) and pride (self-admiration)?

> joy + sadness : bittersweet ::  disgust + admiration: ambivalence

From the Wikipedia, [ambivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambivalence): is a state of having simultaneous conflicting reactions, beliefs, or feelings towards some object. Being [ambivalent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/words-that-do-not-mean-what-you-think-they-mean/suspect#:%7E:text=Being%20ambivalent%20doesn%27t%20mean%20you%20don%27t%20care%2C%20it%20means%20you%20have%20contradictory%20or%20mixed%20feelings%20about%20it.%20You%20do%20care%E2%80%94and%20you%27re%20torn.) doesn't mean you don't care, it means you have contradictory or mixed feelings about it. ... You do care—and you're torn, at the same time.

Comment: No; far too hypernymic. Happy yet anxious. Relieved but sad....

Comment: But OP wants one word.

Comment: Stackexchange is always about answering the OP's question. The constraint here is one word. Period.

Comment: Hypernym : Generic_meaning :: Quaternary_Dyad : Combination_of_Antithetical_Emotions. As per UCLA Professor of Sociology Warren TenHouten, ambivalence is one of four specific quarternary dyads. QED.

Comment: In your words, sad but relieved (~serenity) ~= bittersweet (another quaternary dyad), or happy (low intensity joy) yet anxious (low intensity fear) = guilt (a secondary dyad). Take your pick!

Answer (score 0):

Damn, this code is **a hack**!

> [hack](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hack.html):
>
> 1. n. Originally, a quick job that produces what is needed, but not well.
>
>    n. An incredibly good, and perhaps very time-consuming, piece of work that produces exactly what is needed.
>
> [neat hack](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/neat-hack.html):
>
>   A clever technique.

From [The Jargon File, version 4.4.8](http://www.catb.org/jargon/).

Comment: This correctly fits my previous (incorrect) sample sentence, which I have since edited, but is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a devious character from *Game of Thrones* and turn their name into an adjective by adding “ish” on the end.

More generically, there’s **fiendish**, **devilish**, **machiavellian** and other terms that have softened in their meaning over the years.

Or maybe **shameless**.

Answer (score 0):

Like *[bad](https://www.onelook.com/?w=bad),* ***wicked*** seems to have come to mean
both good (positive) and bad (negative):

> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=wicked):
>
>   1. Evil or immoral …
>   2. Playfully malicious or mischievous:
>   *a wicked prank; a critic's wicked wit.*
>   ︙
>   5.
>   *Slang*
>   Strikingly good, effective, or skillful:
>   *a wicked curve ball; a wicked imitation.*
>
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/wicked):
>
>   1. Evil or morally wrong.
>     ︙
>
> 1.3 Playfully mischievous. 
>   *‘Ben has a wicked sense of humor’*
>
> 1.4 *informal* Excellent; wonderful.
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/wicked_1):
>
>   1. morally wrong and deliberately intending to hurt people
>   ︙
>
> 3. <sup>VERY INFORMAL</sup> 
> very good. 
> This word is used mainly by young people.
>
> [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/wicked):
>
>   *Wicked*
>   has two quite contradictory meanings. 
>   If something is pure evil, then it is
>   *wicked.*
>   Think Darth Vader. 
>   On the other hand, as an informal slang term,
>   *wicked*
>   also means excellent
>   — as in "that DJ is
>   *wicked*
>   , man!" 
>   Go figure.

IMHO, while *bad* means either bad or good,
***wicked*** has the potential to mean both at once. 
YMMV.

Comment: I feel this doesn't address the nub of the question. These are two completely distinct senses, while I feel OP wants a word whose sense is somewhere between disgust and pride.

Comment: The OP needs a word that captures the "feel" (from his own posting) of experiencing the combination of two antithetical emotions. Ambivalence is one (of only four) antithetical dyads that is part of the established pyschological research.